# Namespace and AjaxToolkit Errors in Visual Studio 2008 after installing Visual Studio 2012,

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008, namespaces, web-config, visual-studio-2012

I have been using Visual studio 2008 Professional for a few years.  Last year I downloaded and installed Visual studio 2010 express with no problems.  Recently I downloaded and installed visual studio 2012 web express and now my existing web apps in vs 2008 have numerous errors.  Most of the errors are related to missing namespaces even though they are spelled out in the web.config file.  **What caused these errors and more importantly how can I get rid of them???**

**A few of the errors:** 
Name 'AjaxControlToolkit' is not declared.
Name 'Replace' is not declared. 
Type 'Guid' is not defined.
Type 'List' is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why but after removing the following from web.config everything started working again.

```
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="MySQLRoleProvider">
        <providers>
            <add name="MySQLRoleProvider" connectionStringName="App_DBConnection" applicationName="GRMS 3.0" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxx"/>
        </providers>
    </roleManager>
    <membership defaultProvider="MySqlMembershipProvider">
        <providers>
            <add name="MySqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="App_DBConnection" applicationName="App3.0" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxx" passwordFormat="Encrypted" enablePasswordRetrieval="true" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="7" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="1" passwordAttemptWindow="10" passwordStrengthRegularExpression=""/>
        </providers>
    </membership>
<profile enabled="true" defaultProvider="MySQLProfileProvider">
  <providers>
    <add name="MySQLProfileProvider" connectionStringName="App_DBConnection" applicationName="App 3.0" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxx"/>
  </providers>
  <properties>
    <add name="Name" type="System.String" provider="MySQLProfileProvider" allowAnonymous="true"/>
    <group name="ProjectInfo">
      <add name="CurrProjectID" allowAnonymous="false" type="System.guid"/>
      <add name="CurrProjectName" allowAnonymous="false" type="System.String"/>
    </group>
  </properties>
</profile>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. But fixed it by removing a webreference. Without it everything worked. With it a complaint:
Cannot find LiquidTechnologies.Runtime.Net20, Version=7.1.4.1284, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=64bee40f6e1c14f0.

Talked to the person who made the web-service, but he said no 3rd party dlls were needed...

I do not have the webreference in my solution anymore. So it is not a good solution.

But the problem here could be caused by removed dlss etc from windows/.Net framerok etc...